# restfb: Permanent Access Token

Tags: java, restfb

I am new to restfb, I have created an app in FB developers.

I need to post threads asynchronously to My own FB page.

I have used:

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("QQZAdauSYGcs8JRe3ZCUDWDrRYRKbKxuD9trn6E3C0RLVB5L38164LUGSSMLPojrOWtZCsWgW7zOSC1...");
```

By the way, this access token is getting expired frequently. How can I do this asynchronously without manually getting the Access Token on to FB dev site.

Kindly feel free to ask additional details

Comment: Have you tried the docs? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

Comment: Thanks for comment Bill, I will look into this and revert

Answer (score 0):

RestFB provides a method for this, but you should read the facebook docs anyway.

http://restfb.com/#access-token-extend

```
AccessToken accessToken =
   new DefaultFacebookClient().obtainExtendedAccessToken(MY_APP_ID,
     MY_APP_SECRET, MY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer Norbert, I have tried with this already But got Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. (code 2500, subcode null)

Comment: Without knowing how you code looks like it's a bit hard to give a better advise. But perhaps you should check your access tokens in the token debugger at Facebook.

Comment: @Norbert ... This method that DefaulfFacebookClient with no argument constructor is deprecated that I currently using 1.30 restfb version.  Is there any way to get Accesstoken with MY_APP_ID and MY_APP_SECRET.

Comment: Use a DefaultFacebookClient with a version. The constructor `new DefaultFacebookClient(Version.LATEST)` is not deprecated.